# How to create gradle multi-project in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle

I am new to gradle and am trying to create a directory layout as such in netbeans:

```
myproject
    |
|-- ear
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- ...
|-- core
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- ...
|-- web
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- include core project as dependency for this project
    |-- ...
|-- settings.gradle // has include "ear", "core", "web"
```

I cant find a way to do this, in Google. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create these files on disk and open the project in NetBeans. I assume you have a plugin with Gradle support installed. I think there are no such wizards to guide you through multi-project build setup.

If you have Gradle downloaded and installed you can take a look at bundled samples (in `samples` folder).

Comment: Agree with @Radim, there is no wizard to guide through the multiproject build. Also in netbeans when you open a gradle multi-project, it just shows you the root project;
You need to expand "Subprojects" item in project navigator and then right click on desired subproject you want to open and select "Open <project>" button.